# Flutter I can not update the profile picture

Tags: flutter, flutter-image, flutter-image-picker, flutter-file

I am trying to built a profile picture and also using a firestore. I can not update the selected profile picture on the screen I need to hot refresh for it. The question is how can I update it and display it on the screen when the user select another profile picture

```
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
```

This is my image picker:

```
Future uploadProfilePicture() async {
    final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxWidth: 500,
      maxHeight: 500,
    );

    Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("profilePic.jpg");
    await ref.putFile(File(image!.path));
    ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        imageURL = value;
        user.updatePhotoURL(value);
      });
    });
  }
```

This is how I display it on the screen:

```
 GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        uploadProfilePicture();
                      },
                      child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          child: ProfilePicture(
                            name: user.displayName!,
                            radius: 40,
                            fontsize: 20,
                            img: user.photoURL,
                          )),
                    )
```

Comment: Can you post your 'user' method?

Comment: yes, sorry for that;